# ASP.NET RadioButtonList generating extra HTML for a ListItem that contains an image

Tags: asp.net, radiobuttonlist

In my application I have a RadioButtonList:

```
<asp:RadioButtonList runat="server" ID="CardTypeRadioButtonList" RepeatDirection="Horizontal">
    <asp:ListItem Value="Visa">
        <img src="../images/icon_visa.gif" alt="Visa" align="absmiddle">&nbsp;Visa
    </asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Value="MasterCard">
        <img src="../images/icon_mc.gif" alt="MasterCard" align="absmiddle">&nbsp;Mastercard
    </asp:ListItem>
</asp:RadioButtonList>
```

However, sometimes Visual Studio generates the following code automatically and inserts it into my ListItems:

```
&lt;img src=&quot;../images/icon_visa.gif&quot; alt=&quot;Visa&quot; align=&quot;absmiddle&quot;&gt;&#160;Visa
```

Any idea how to make this go away?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried putting a blank Text attribute on each ListItem.  Hopefully this makes this issue go away.

Answer (score 0):

you are missing '<' at the second 'img' tag

```
<asp:RadioButtonList runat="server" ID="CardTypeRadioButtonList" RepeatDirection="Horizontal">
<asp:ListItem Value="Visa">
    <img src="../images/icon_visa.gif" alt="Visa" align="absmiddle"> Visa
</asp:ListItem>
<asp:ListItem Value="MasterCard">
   <img src="../images/icon_mc.gif" alt="MasterCard" align="absmiddle"> Mastercard
</asp:ListItem>
```

Comment: That happened when I copied and pasted the code.  It is fixed in the original message - thanks for noticing.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue with Telerik controls about a year ago and ended up writing a macro to fix it as needed because I couldn't figure it out. That's not the best solution but if you can't figure out what to do its very easy to create a macro to repair the code as needed in Visual Studio.

Comment: So far my solution of adding a blank Text attribute to the list item object seems to be working.  It's had to re-create the problem, but if I go a week or two without it happening again I'll call it good.